# Contact processing failed. Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics

Tags: wffm

Whenever I click on submit for a WFFM form, the form does not submit and displays the `We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.` error.

Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

In the error logs I see the following errors as well:

**ERROR Contact processing failed. Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics...**

```
18468 2017:03:01 17:27:38 ERROR Contact processing failed. Service 

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Abstractions.ISettingsAnalytics was not registered in container
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Abstractions.ISettingsAnalytics was not registered in container
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.ObjectLocator.GetInstance[TService]()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Extensions.ContactExtensions.ShouldBeIndexed(IContact contact)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.ContactChangeContactAggregator.<ResolveIndexables>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.ObservablePipelineProcessorHelper`3.OnProcess(TArgs args, String source)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipelines.ContactProcessing.ContactProcessingPipeline.Run(ContactProcessingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Data.Contact.ContactProcessingAgent.Execute()
```

**ERROR Aggregation Error**

```
6680 2017:03:01 17:27:38 ERROR Aggregation Error
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Abstractions.ISettingsAnalytics was not registered in container
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.ObjectLocator.GetInstance[TService]()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Extensions.ContactExtensions.ShouldBeIndexed(IContact contact)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsVisitAggregator.<ResolveIndexables>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.ObservablePipelineProcessorHelper`3.OnProcess(TArgs args, String source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.AggregationProcessor.Process(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
```

**ERROR Error during aggregation.**

```
6680 2017:03:01 17:27:38 ERROR Error during aggregation.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Abstractions.ISettingsAnalytics was not registered in container
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.ObjectLocator.GetInstance[TService]()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Extensions.ContactExtensions.ShouldBeIndexed(IContact contact)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsVisitAggregator.<ResolveIndexables>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.ObservablePipelineProcessorHelper`3.OnProcess(TArgs args, String source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.AggregationProcessor.Process(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.AggregationPipeline.Run(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregator.Aggregate(Byte[] recordKey, IAggregationContext context)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Aggregator.Execute()
```

**Screenshot of the Include Directory:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Adding the following block of XML to the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config got rid of the three above errors in the error log.

```
<hooks>
  <hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" />
</hooks>
```

But, the `We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.` error is still present.

I am not seeing any relevant errors. But, there are warnings. I created a basic console application and verified that the server can send email via the SMTP server configured.

**WARN [WFFM] Failure sending mail.**

```
8612 2017:03:02 15:48:35 WARN [WFFM] Failure sending mail.
Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
Message: Failure sending mail.
Source: System
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplMailSender.SendMail(IEmailAttributes emailAttributes, ID formId, AdaptedResultList fields, Object[] data)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actionDefinitions, Boolean simpleAdapt, ID sessionID)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: System
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.175.228:25
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

**WARN [WFFM] The 'Send Email Message**

```
8612 2017:03:02 15:48:35 WARN [WFFM] The 'Send Email Message[id={D4502A11-9417-4479-9F2A-485F45D2E2D0}]' save action failed: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.
```

**WARN [WFFM] Web Forms for Marketers: an exception**

```
8612 2017:03:02 15:48:35 WARN [WFFM] Web Forms for Marketers: an exception: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved. has occured while trying to execute an action.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The wrong host parameter was found in the Submit Parameters value for the Send Email Message item. After correcting this value the emails are sending fine.

Comment: do you have analytics enabled on this instance?

Comment: I changed the follow key from true to false. Could that be the issue? <setting name="Analytics.PerformLookup" value="false" />

Comment: How can I tell if analytics is enabled?

Comment: there is a config under /app_config/include/Sitecore.XDB.config and check this tag
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled"  />

Comment: you can always double check whether your analytics is collecting data on mongo

Comment: From showconfig.xml <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Xdb.config" />

Comment: how do I check Mongo?

Comment: this is a 7.5 example but should point you to the right direction
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/sitecore-and-xdb-setting-up-mongodb-on-your-developer-machine/

Comment: If the email is sent fine, now you have to check which other save action is failing for your form? what are the save actions you have and do you see any new errors ([WFFM]) in logs?

Comment: The wrong host parameter was found in the Submit Parameters value for the Send Email Message item. After correcting this value the emails are sending fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that I see that makes sense to me that I see in your error messages is:

> **Service
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Abstractions.ISettingsAnalytics was
>   not registered in container**

This indicates to me that `ISettingsAnalytics` isn't registered in the DI container.

I would check to make sure you have **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config** enabled.  This config, among other things, adds the initialization hook that registers `ISettingsAnalytics` to the container.

```xml
<hooks>
  <hook type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" />
</hooks>
```

If this config file is enabled, check the **ShowConfig.aspx** page and do a search for *Analytics.Hooks.Initializer* and see if it's present.

Comment: The config is enabled. Analytics.Hooks.Initializer is not present.

Comment: It is present now, but the form is still returning the "technical difficulty" error.

Comment: What are the errors now?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled Solr and Lucene at the same time for the same index. Particularly Analytics index seems to be miss-behaving here. You may have to [reconfigure your indexing](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider) to use either Solr or Lucene. You cannot have both enabled at the same time for the same index.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: Your screen shot above show both `*.Lucene.*.config` and `*.Solr.*.config` files enabled.

Comment: My suggestion is if you don't know what is the config file for do not modify it. by default all Sitecore.*.solr.*.config files are disabled